# How to create a custom top-level layer 2 header in scapy?

Tags: networking, scapy, packet, packet-sniffers

Say I have the following:

```
class Delimiter(Packet):
    name = "Delimiter"
    fields_desc = [
        ByteField("val", 0)
    ]

class OutHeader(Packet):
    name = "Out Header"
    fields_desc = [
        ShortField("index", 0)
    ]

bind_layers(Delimiter, OutHeader, val=0)
bind_layers(OutHeader, Ether)
```

And I want to make `Delimeter` a layer 2 header, such that there is no Ether header at the top of the packet. How can I do this? With just this code, Scapy reads this instead:

```
###[ 802.3 ]###
  dst       = 00:51:99:ff:ff:ff
  src       = ff:ff:ff:00:00:00
  len       = 0
###[ Padding ]###
```

Comment: I think you are confusing the network layers. Packets are layer-3, which are the payload of layer-2 (e.g. ethernet) frames.

Comment: @RonMaupin Thanks for the response. No, I am referring to my observation that Scapy seems to start dissecting packets at Layer 2, but I don't know how to define a layer such as Ether, Dot3, etc. at the front of the packet.

Comment: You do not do that. The data-link layer is defined by the interface and driver. You cannot, for example, send token-ring frames on an ethernet interface, or vice versa. There is no field for the frame type the way that the frame has an EtherType, or the packet has a Protocol field, etc.

Comment: @RonMaupin I suppose that is the case. Still, note the raw bytes of the packet. 00 is clearly the delimeter, 51:99 is clearly the Out Header and ff:.... is the destination MAC. I just want to parse the packet in that format.

Comment: For ethernet, there is a seven-octet Synchronization (alternating ones and zeros), then a one-octet Start-of-Frame delimiter (alternating ones and zeros until the last bit, which is also one, making two ones in a row), then the frame starts with the destination MAC address. Also, at the end of the frame, there is a 12-octet igap of silence on the line That is how an ethernet frame is delimited. There is not `00` frame delimiter. The frame starts immediately after the `11` in the SoF. Other data-link protocols do it differently.

Comment: The Synchronization, SoF, and gap are all controlled in layer-1 by the hardware, which will not pass that up to the layer-2 protocol, so that is never seen by the software.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I think I should clarify that I am not attempting to parse the preamble of an ethernet packet. I am sending an ethernet packet on one machine, using a model programmable switch to add the two custom headers shown onto the front of the packet, and forwarding exactly that to another server. Are you saying the underlying hardware is making it impossible to coerce Scapy into reading the packet correctly?

Comment: The hardware is not passing the Preamble, SoF, and gap up to the software. You need specialized equipment to see those.

Comment: Most modern ethernet interfaces will also handle the FCS in hardware, and they will only pass a good frame to the software, so you may never see a bad frame or the FCS, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved the problem by manually slicing off the headers, without custom Packet objects:

```
s = str(pkt).encode("hex")
delim = int(s[:2])
index = int(s[2:6], 16)
rest = Ether(s[6:].decode("hex"))
```